# How to invert a music track? (FL Studio / Audacity)

Tags: audio, daw, sound-editing

I am trying to invert my music track, I don't mean reverse it, invert it like here

[image]

to make the first one be like second one. (Its flipped in the picture).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called reversing the polarity of the audio. You can easily do this in any modern DAW. I will describe the procedure for doing this in FL Studio:

- Open the audio sample in Edison.
- Right-click and go to tools drop down list
- Click on the reverse polarity option.

A quick Google search reveals many blogs and videos about reversing/inverting polarity for various DAWs (including FL Studio).

Answer (score 1):

In Audacity you can invert polarity by clicking `Effect > Invert`

Comment: Might be better just to add it as an edit to the existing answer